# Twisted TCP server with a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, twisted

recently I've been experimenting with Twisted (python library) in an attempt to make a TCP chat server/client. I had the server running nicely but when I tried to add a Tkinter-based GUI to the server, things got weird. As soon as a user connects to the server, a message is sent to the GUI. However, somewhere along the way something goes wrong and a long-winded error comes up, the gist of which is that Tkinter ran out of stack space because of an infinite loop. I've put my code below. The function that I am having trouble with is App.write(text) and User.connectionMade(*args) as well as any other function in the User class that attempts to print text to the GUI.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ServerFactory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
from os import path
import yaml
import threading
from Tkinter import *

__version__ = ''
__author__ = ''

class User(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self,*args):
        self.gui.write('New connection from %s' % (self.addr.host))
        self.transport.write('Username: ')

    def connectionLost(self,reason):
        self.gui.write('Connection lost with %s' % (self.addr.host))
        if not self.name == None:
            msg = '%s has disconnected\r\n' % (self.name)
            self.gui.write(msg.rstrip())
            self.toAll(msg)
            del self.users[self.name]

    def dataReceived(self,data):
        if data == '\x08':
            if len(self.text) > 0:
                self.text = self.text[:-1]
            return 
        elif not data.endswith('\r\n'):
            self.text += data
            return
        if self.name == None:
            self.setName(self.text)
        else:
            self.handle(self.text)
        self.text = ''

    def handle(self,data):
        if not data.startswith('/'):
            self.chat(data)
        else:
            self.gui.write('%s executed command %s' % (self.name, data))
            if data in ['/help','/h']: self.cmdHelp()
            elif data in ['/list','/l']: self.userList()
            elif data in ['/motd','/m']: self.sendMotd()
            elif data in ['/ping','/p']: self.transport.write('Pong!\r\n')
            else: self.transport.write('Unrecognized command %s\r\n' % (data))

    def cmdHelp(self):
        x = ['\r\nCOMMANDS:',\
             '/motd,/m - Display the MOTD',\
             '/list,/l - Display a list of online users',\
             '/help,/h - Display this list\r\n']
        for item in x:
            self.transport.write(item+'\r\n')

    def sendMotd(self):
        self.transport.write('\r\nMOTD: %s\r\n\r\n' % (self.motd))

    def userList(self):
        self.transport.write('\r\nCURRENTLY ONLINE: server,%s\r\n\r\n' % (','.join(item for item in self.users)))

    def setName(self,name):
        if self.users.has_key(name) or name.lower() == 'server':
            self.transport.write('That username is in use!\r\nUsername: ')
        elif ' ' in name:
            self.transport.write('No spaces are allowed in usernames!\r\nUsername: ')
        elif name == '':
            self.transport.write('You must enter a username!\r\nUsername: ')
        else:
            self.users[name] = self
            self.name = name
            self.gui.write('New user registered as %s' % (name))
            self.toAll('%s has connected' % (self.name))
            self.transport.write('\nSuccessfully logged in as %s\r\n\r\n' % (name))
            self.sendMotd()

    def toAll(self,msg):
        for name,protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if not protocol == self:
                protocol.transport.write(msg)

    def chat(self,data):
        to_self = '<%s (you)> %s\r\n' % (self.name, data)
        to_else = '<%s> %s\r\n' % (self.name, data)
        self.gui.write('[CHAT] - %s' % (to_else.rstrip()))
        self.transport.write(to_self)
        self.toAll(to_else)

    def __init__(self,addr=None,users=None,motd=None,master=None):
        self.name = None
        self.addr = addr
        self.users = users
        self.motd = motd
        self.text = ''
        self.factory = master
        self.gui = self.factory.app
        self.kicked = False

class App(Frame):
    def write(self,text):
        self.display.insert(END,text+'\n')

    def clear(self,event=None):
        self.display.delete(1.0,END)

    def userList(self):
        self.write('Currently online: server,%s' % (','.join(item for item in self.factory.users)))

    def handle(self,event=None):
        msg = self.entry.get()
        self.entry.delete(0,END)
        if not msg.startswith('/'): self.send(msg)
        elif msg in ['/cls','/clear','/clr','/c']: self.clear()
        elif msg in ['/list','/l']: self.userList()
        elif msg in ['/exit']: self.kill()
        else: self.write('Unrecognized command \'%s\'' % (msg))

    def send(self,msg,event=None):
        for item in self.factory.users: self.factory.users[item].transport.write('<server> %s\r\n' % (msg))
        self.write('[CHAT] - <server> %s' % (msg))

    def kill(self):
        self.write('Stopping server...')
        reactor.stop()
        self.write('GUI says guidbye! :(')
        self.quit()

    def __init__(self,master,factory):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid(row=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.display = Text(self)
        self.display.grid(row=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)
        self.yscroll = Scrollbar(self,command=self.display.yview)
        self.yscroll.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)
        self.display.config(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll.set)
        self.entry = Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(row=1,sticky=E+W)
        self.master = master

        self.master.wm_title('TCP Chat Server v%s' % (__version__))
        self.factory = factory

        self.motd = ''
        self.port = 0

        self.entry.bind('<Return>',self.handle)
        self.master.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self.kill)

        self.write('TCP Chat Server v%s' % (__version__))
        self.write('by %s\n' % (__author__))
        self.write('Server currently running on port %s' % (self.factory.port))

class Main(ServerFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self,addr):
        return User(addr=addr,users=self.users,motd=self.motd,master=self)

    def start(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.app = App(self.root,self)
        self.app.mainloop()

    def __init__(self,motd,port):
        self.users = {}
        self.motd = motd
        self.port = port

        self.tk_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start)
        self.tk_thread.start()


if not path.isfile('config.yml'):
    open('config.yml','w').write('port: 4444\nmotd: No motd set!')

with open('config.yml','r') as f:
    dump = yaml.load(f.read())
    motd = dump['motd']
    port = dump['port']

reactor.listenTCP(port,Main(motd,port))
reactor.run()
```

Everything else is running as expected, and when I comment out the App.write('') statements, the program runs as expected (sans GUI and server-side messages). I've been using Windows to test the program so I use

```
telnet localhost 4444
```

to run the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted has some [specialised support](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/core/howto/choosing-reactor.html#tkinter) for Tkinter.

```
from Tkinter import *
from twisted.internet import tksupport, reactor

root = Tk()

# Install the Reactor support
tksupport.install(root)

# at this point build Tk app as usual using the root object,
# and start the program with "reactor.run()", and stop it
# with "reactor.stop()".
```

Comment: Make sure to add `root.destroy()` to the end of the program or else the Tk window will stay up.